# How to plot the best fit line of two variables where the variable on the x-axis is a categorical variable (str) and not a number in Python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-visualization, seaborn, data-science

I want to plot the best fit line of two variables.

I used the `seaborn.regplot()` method but it shows one of the axis is 'str' and cannot be converted to 'float'. Can someone suggest me a way to do this plot?

My values are like:

`x = [10, 11, 12, 9, 14]`

`y = ['2013-14', '2014-15', '2015-16', '2016-17', '2017-18']`

Comment: Since your items in y seems to be two consecutive years, could you just split the string and keep the first year of the two "concatenate" year as variable ? : `[int(item[0:4]) for item in y]`

Comment: @Clément I cannot do that as it will defeat the purpose of my plot. Is there any way to plot the best fit line of the trend keeping the variable as it is?

Comment: Can you provide some code ?

Comment: @Clément  plt.scatter(x = df['values'], y = df['Year Ranges'])
sns.lineplot(x = df['values'], y = df['Year Ranges'])
plt.title('Title')
plt.show()

Comment: If you use lineplot it must be numeric : `Input data variables; must be numeric.`

Comment: Create a dummy numeric y_axis: `np.arange(len(y))` and then you can modify the `yticklabels` with the elements within the list: `ax.set_yticklabels(y)`.

Comment: @Cowflu It is not working. it shows that 'ax' not defined

Comment: @Clément You are right. But the axis is categorical. Any way to solve that?